Class "FFMpeg\FFMpeg" not found
I installed ffmpeg on xampp by COMPOSER. I installed FFMPEG on windows before.

Then with the command composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg installed php-ffmpeg

I use code below (from php-ffmpeg github) for a test but this does not work
<?php

require '../../phpMyAdmin/vendor/autoload.php';

$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(); // line 5 that error referees to 
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
$video
    ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
    ->save('frame.jpg');
$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WMV(), 'export-wmv.wmv')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'export-webm.webm');

?>

This is the error I encounter.

I read many and many similar questions but almost all of them suggest require '../../phpMyAdmin/vendor/autoload.php';  that I have it in my code.

Did you install the necessary binaries as per the documentation?

The PHP extension is missing...

@geertjanknapen your suggestion says "This library requires PHP 8.0 or higher" . Mine is 8.2.4 .

@HonkderHase can you say more clear please ? what do you mean with php extension ?

The question itself is a beginner question, but it's written well. It includes all information needed: The Code, the error thrown, what has been tried and sources for code snippets (e.g. the ffmpeg documentation). Is there a reason for downvoting this then? Only because the answer is obvious to you it doesn't mean it is obvious for everyone.

@Brentspine possibly due to the images within the code. And possibly also the fact that there is no real question.

@Brentspine I wonder too!

@geertjanknapen What do you mean with "no real question" ? By the way images are not codes, they are results of commands.

Well you are not asking a question, a question is implied.
